# Restoring DB requires us to recycle IIS application pool

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis, sql-server-2012, nunit

We have a strange situation regarding our web tests (basically NUnit tests):

- In the `SetUp` method each test restores the database
- *Sometimes* all subsequent tests fail with the following `SqlException`:

  SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "OurDatabaseName" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'.
- Access rights however are correct, so the error is misleading.
- As soon as we recycle the IIS app pool for the application everything is back to normal

This problem occurs approx. in one of five executions. If we remove the database restore call -> no problems at all. There seems to be some kind of race condition when restoring our database, which doesn't close the old connections in some way?!

Is there special code we have to execute after restoring a database to forcefully kill all connections to the database or something like that?

We already call `SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();` after restoring the database (however, from the web test project ... so don't know if this has any effect on the web application).

Comment: What happens if you retry?. Try to dispose, recreate and reopen the connection on failure.

Comment: Retry by means of browser-refresh in the web test? => same result until we recycle the app pool. Retry on the server => how to decide when to retry? This SqlException is pretty generic/misleading and may be even valid in some cases...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something is blocking the connection. Ensure that you have either remote connections turned off or antivirus may be the cause of the failure. Check your antivirus log or quarantined list whether the services of sql server is in the list if present then try to move it to the exclusion list.

Comment: But what is blocking the connection? And why only in some cases? There is no anti-virus tool on our internal test servers. Also all your suggestions would hint that it either works all the time or never.